# Javascript - Updating ParentId to in nested objects

Tags: javascript, nested-object

I currently store a structure in a javascript Array with nested objects. The structure does not have a parentId parameter which I do need to get the parent of a nested object. The current structure outputs:

```
    [{
        "id":1000,
        "pageIndex":0,
        "type":"page",
        "label":"Page 1",
        "rows":[
            {
                "id":1002,
                "type":"row 1",
                "layout":{
                    "gutters":true,
                    "wrapping":false,
                    "guttersDirect":false,
                    "parentId":1002
                },
                "columns":[
                    {
                        "id":1003,
                        "type":"col 1",
                        "layout":{
                            "size":3,
                            "outOf":12,
                            "parentId":1003
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id":1004,
                        "type":"col 2",
                        "layout":{
                            "size":3,
                            "outOf":12,
                            "parentId":1004
                        },
                        "elements":[
                            {
                                "id":1006,
                                "type":"text",
                                "label":"Account ID"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id":1005,
                        "type":"col 3",
                        "layout":{
                            "size":6,
                            "outOf":12,
                            "parentId":1005
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }]
```

I need a function that updates all nested objects' parentId attribute with the parent nested object's id.

I have the following function

```
   _PREV_PARENT_ID = null;
    assignParentIds(object){
        Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
            console.log(`key: ${key}, value: ${object[key]}`)
            if(key === "id"){
                this._PREV_PARENT_ID = object[key];
            }else if (typeof object[key] === 'object') {
                if(!!this._PREV_PARENT_ID){
                    object[key]['parentId'] = this._PREV_PARENT_ID;
                }
                this.assignParentIds(object[key])
            }
        });
    }
```

However, this function fails to set parent ids correctly for items in array

```
[
    {
        "id":1000,
        "pageIndex":0,
        "type":"page",
        "label":"Page 1",
        "rows":[
            {
                "id":1002,
                "parentId":1000,
                "type":"row 1",
                "layout":{
                    "gutters":true,
                    "wrapping":false,
                    "guttersDirect":false,
                    "parentId":1002
                },
                "columns":[
                    {
                        "id":1003,
                        "parentId":1002, <--- Correct
                        "type":"col 1",
                        "layout":{
                            "size":3,
                            "outOf":12,
                            "parentId":1003
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "id":1004,
                        "parentId":1003, <--- In-Correct
                        "type":"col 2",
                        "layout":{
                            "size":3,
                            "outOf":12,
                            "parentId":1004
                        },
                        "elements":[
                            {
                                "id":1006,
                                "parentId":1004,
                                "type":"text",
                                "label":"Account ID"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "id":1005,
                        "parentId":1006, <--- In-Correct
                        "type":"col 3",
                        "layout":{
                            "size":6,
                            "outOf":12,
                            "parentId":1005
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I thought about also potentially ditching parentId attribute and instead to use a function that would return the parent nested, however it also suffers from the same issue (if I call the function on id = 1004, it returns the previous item in the array with id = 1003 instead of returning the object with id 1002.

```
_PARENT_OBJECT = null;
    findParentByChildId(o, id) {
        if( o.id === id ){
            return o;
        }else{
            if(o.hasOwnProperty('id')){
                this._PARENT_OBJECT = o;
            }
        }
        var result, p; 
        for (p in o) {          
            if( o.hasOwnProperty(p) && typeof o[p] === 'object' ) {             
                result = this.findParentByChildId(o[p], id);
                if(result){                 
                    return this._PARENT_OBJECT;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;  
        
    }
```

Since the use case is about using drag and drop functionality, the parentId will often be updated and seems like an uneccesary extra attribute that we need to keep track of, it would be best if I had a way to call a function findParentByChildId().

What would be the best way to manage this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to take a chance to figure it out. I've made a walker function which goes through every level and array and brings the id of the previous level with it. Then when it gets a match on an id it returns the parent id you are looking for. Or when it has no match it returns `null`.

```js
const data = [{
  "id": 1000,
  "pageIndex": 0,
  "type": "page",
  "label": "Page 1",
  "rows": [{
    "id": 1002,
    "type": "row 1",
    "layout": {
      "gutters": true,
      "wrapping": false,
      "guttersDirect": false,
      "parentId": 1002
    },
    "columns": [{
        "id": 1003,
        "type": "col 1",
        "layout": {
          "size": 3,
          "outOf": 12,
          "parentId": 1003
        }
      },
      {
        "id": 1004,
        "type": "col 2",
        "layout": {
          "size": 3,
          "outOf": 12,
          "parentId": 1004
        },
        "elements": [{
          "id": 1006,
          "type": "text",
          "label": "Account ID"
        }]
      },
      {
        "id": 1005,
        "type": "col 3",
        "layout": {
          "size": 6,
          "outOf": 12,
          "parentId": 1005
        }
      }
    ]
  }]
}];

const walkTree = (entry, matchId, parentId = null) => {
  let result = null;
  for (const { id, ...rest } of entry) {
    if (matchId === id) {
      return parentId;
    }
    parentId = id;
    for (const value of Object.values(rest)) {
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        result = walkTree(value, matchId, parentId);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
};

const findParentByChildId = id => walkTree(data, id);

// ID's to look up parents of.
const lookupParents = [
  1000,
  1002,
  1003,
  1004,
  1005,
  1006,
  1007
];

// Log results.
for (const id of lookupParents) {
  console.log(`Parent of ${id}:`, findParentByChildId(id));
}
```